# Grafana "Invalid username or password" on localhost

Tags: grafana

Runnning Grafana on `https://localhost:3000`, my password seems to have stopped working.

- I tried resetting the admin password with `grafana-cli --homepath /usr/local/share/grafana admin reset-admin-password admin` and
- reinstalling Grafana,

but keep getting "Invalid username or password".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On macOS, this solved the issue for me:

```
$ find / -type f -name grafana.db
```

With the file found above

```
$ sudo sqlite3 /usr/local/var/lib/grafana/grafana.db
```

Finally

```
sqlite> update user set password = '59acf18b94d7eb0694c61e60ce44c110c7a683ac6a8f09580d626f90f4a242000746579358d77dd9e570e83fa24faa88a8a6', salt = 'F3FAxVm33R' where login = 'admin';
sqlite> .exit
```

**This will set the username/password to admin/admin.**

Answer (score 0):

`grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password admin123`

`systemctl restart grafana-server`

#ps:admin123 means your new password